# How to Write Conditional Statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am having a logic issue in relation to querying an SQL database. I need to exclude 3 different categories and any item that is included in those categories; however, if an item under one of those categories meets the criteria for another category I need to keep said item.

This is an example output I will get after querying the database at its current version:

```
ExampleDB | item_num | pro_type | area     | description

    1     | 45KX-76Y |   FLCM   | Finished | coil8x
    2     | 68WO-93H |   FLCL   | Similar  | y45Kx
    3     | 05RH-27N |   FLDR   | Finished | KH72n
    4     | 84OH-95W |   FLEP   | Final    | tar5x
    5     | 81RS-67F |   FLEP   | Final    | tar7x
    6     | 48YU-40Q |   FLCM   | Final    | bile6
    7     | 19VB-89S |   FLDR   | Warranty | exp380
    8     | 76CS-01U |   FLCL   | Gator    | low5
    9     | 28OC-08Z |   FLCM   | Redo     | coil34Y
```

item_num and description are in a table together, and pro_type and area are in 2 separate tables--a total of 3 tables to pull data from.

I need to construct a query that will not pull back any item_num where area is equal to: Finished, Final, and Redo; but I also need to pull in any item_num that meets the type criteria: FLCM and FLEP. In the end my query should look like this:

```
ExampleDB | item_num | pro_type | area     | description

    1     | 45KX-76Y |   FLCM   | Finished | coil8x
    2     | 68WO-93H |   FLCL   | Similar  | y45Kx
    3     | 84OH-95W |   FLEP   | Final    | tar5x
    4     | 81RS-67F |   FLEP   | Final    | tar7x
    5     | 19VB-89S |   FLDR   | Warranty | exp380
    6     | 76CS-01U |   FLCL   | Gator    | low5
    7     | 28OC-08Z |   FLCM   | Redo     | coil34Y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from table
join...
where area not in('finished', 'final', 'redo') or type in('flcm', 'flep')
```

Comment: Thank you. The actual query I am using is enormous and I was easily lost trying to navigate it. I had to add more to your solution, but the basics were the same and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_1
JOIN Table_ProType ON Table_1.whatnot = Table_ProType.whatnot
JOIN Table_Area ON Table_1.whatnot = Table_Area.whatnot
WHERE Table.area NOT IN ('Finished','Final','Redo') OR ProType.pro_type IN ('FLCM','FLEP')
```

Giving the names of the three tables and the joining criteria will help me improve the answer.